# Block directory access in IIS but allow specific file through

Tags: iis, web.config

Is it possible to block access to a directory through the web.config in IIS (excluding a small set of IPs) but allow through one specific file for everyone.

The reason I ask, I want to block the wp-admin directory in WordPress but the admin-ajax.php does need to be externally accessible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

For future reference, this was the solution:

```
<location path="wp-admin">
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false">
    <clear/> 
                <add ipAddress="ipaddr" allowed="true" />
            </ipSecurity>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</location>

<location path="wp-admin/admin-ajax.php">
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="true">
            </ipSecurity>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution noted requires ipSecurity overrideModeDefault to be set to Allow in applicationhost.config otherwise you'll receive a 500.19 - Internal Server Error with Error Code 0x80070021

```
<section name="ipSecurity" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
```